# How do I add a proxy to a Websocket?

Tags: javascript, c#

This code works normally if there is one user, but if there is more than one user requesting the service, a problem occurs for the main server "spam messages"
How can I add proxy Calss  and remove the connection client-side and apply a server-side solution

thank you

```
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using Websocket.Client;

namespace TraderMadeWebSocketTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private string streaming_API_Key = "streaming_api_key";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prg = new Program();
            prg.Initialize();
        }
        private void Initialize()
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            try
            {
                var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                var url = new Uri("wss://marketdata.tradermade.com/feedadv");
                using (var client = new WebsocketClient(url))
                {
                    client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Reconnection happened, type: " + info.Type);
                    });
                    client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + msg);
                        if (msg.ToString().ToLower() == "connected")
                        {
                            string data = "{\"userKey\":\"" + streaming_api_key + "\", \"symbol\":\"EURUSD,GBPUSD,USDJPY\"}";
                            client.Send(data);
                        }
                    });
                    client.Start();
                    exitEvent.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Hi all
This code works normally if there is one user, but if there is more than one user requesting the service, a problem occurs for the main server "spam messages"
How can I add proxy Calss  and remove the connection client-side and apply a server-side solution

thank you

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're facing is that the current code is designed for a single client connection. When multiple users try to connect, they all send messages to the server, which can be seen as spam.

To solve this, you can create a proxy server that manages all the client connections and forwards only the necessary messages to the main server. This way, the main server only communicates with the proxy server, and the proxy server manages all the client connections.

Here's a basic outline of how you can implement this:

1. **Proxy Server**: This will be a new server application that listens for client connections. It will manage all the client connections and forward only the necessary messages to the main server.
2. **Client**: The client will connect to the proxy server instead of the main server.
3. **Main Server**: This remains unchanged, but it will now only communicate with the proxy server.

Here's a basic implementation of the proxy server:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Websocket.Client;

namespace ProxyServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static WebsocketClient mainServerClient;
        private static Uri mainServerUri = new Uri("wss://marketdata.tradermade.com/feedadv");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeMainServerConnection();
            StartProxyServer();
        }

        private static void InitializeMainServerConnection()
        {
            mainServerClient = new WebsocketClient(mainServerUri);
            mainServerClient.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            mainServerClient.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reconnection to main server happened, type: " + info.Type);
            });
            mainServerClient.Start();
        }

        private static void StartProxyServer()
        {
            // Here, you'll start a WebSocket server that listens for client connections.
            // For each client connection, you'll handle the messages and forward only the necessary ones to the main server.
            // You can use libraries like Fleck or WebSocket-Sharp to create a WebSocket server in C#.
        }
    }
}
```

In the `StartProxyServer` method, you'll need to implement the WebSocket server that listens for client connections. You can use libraries like Fleck or WebSocket-Sharp for this purpose.

The client will now connect to the proxy server, and the proxy server will manage the connections and forward the necessary messages to the main server.

This is a basic outline, and you'll need to fill in the details based on your specific requirements. The main idea is to offload the client management to the proxy server and let the main server only communicate with the proxy server.

Comment: thank you Mr jimmykurian
If we assume that the proxy uses the address http://127.0.0.1:8080
The problem I encountered in creating a proxy server